# We were a couple of letters deep

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

In [a Quora reply](https://www.quora.com/Whats-going-in-your-mind#), a poster writes that he sent a letter to someone looking for a pen pal:

> In any case, I wrote a lovely little letter to a British boy by the name of James Brown (which sounds like a fake name used by a sex offender). And my new mate James Brown wrote back.… And let me tell you, it was a real treat.…
>
> And so, I wrote back. I even called him ‘Jim’ instead of James.
>
> As we were a couple of letters **deep**, it felt like the right time to
>   elevate the friendship.

Actually I have never heard the word *deep* used in such a context before and I tried to find example sentences but nothing came up.

I'm not sure if *deep* here indicates the action of exchanging letters like when we use the preposition "in" to indicate the action of doing something in sentences such as

> I lost interest after I had been a couple of pages ***in***.

Is using *deep* in that sentence correct?

Comment: Where did you read the first sentence? Can you provide me with a link? It doesn't sound very familiar to my learner mind.

Comment: @Cardinal I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I've gone ahead and reopened the question.  That extra context can really help with understanding a sentence like this one.

Comment: "we were a couple of letters deep" is a completely understandable way of expressing that a relationship of letters had deepened after two letters.